# WARNING [cache] Failed to save key

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, nginx

I get the following warning whenever I do a SQL call to a MySQL database

```
07:36:46 WARNING   [cache] Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DAppBundle%5CEntity%5CBusinessUnit%24_maxid%5D%5B1%5D" (integer) 
["key" => "%5B%5BC%5DAppBundle%5CEntity%5CBusinessUnit%24_maxid%5D%5B1%5D","type" => "integer","exception" => ErrorException { …}] []
```

What is the cause of this warning?

How serious is it?

How can I prevent it?

I'm using a nginx server and the Symfony 3.3.5@stable framework.

**Edit**

This works fine in development and only gives these errors on the production server.

Comment: Can you provide more information (Symfony version, when it's happening,...), maybe related https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21995

Comment: The most important part is `ErrorException` part which is missing in your error report. please add that

Comment: @neodan i think you might have the answer APC cache is disabled for cli
bwt-code@hilt-docker01:/etc/php/7.0$ php -i | grep apc.enable
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
But when I try fin it in the php.ini to change it it's not there
bwt-code@hilt-docker01:/etc/php/7.0$ grep -r enable_cli
cli/php.ini:;opcache.enable_cli=0
fpm/php.ini.ucf-dist:;opcache.enable_cli=0
fpm/php.ini:;opcache.enable_cli=0
How else can I set it to by enabled?

Comment: @Neodan using symfony 3.3.5, It seems like it happens when doctrine does a sql call using query builder.

Comment: @SarahRichardson, Can you show your Entity class `AppBundle\Entity\Business...` and Where you call in Controller?

Comment: @Trix I'm not getting any `ErrorExceptions` just `Warnings`

Comment: Try `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev I get the same warnings with `doctrine:schema:update`

Comment: But you have enlisted that `"exception" => ErrorException`!!! . What OS is installed on your server? Is that MS Windows? Do you use any **Byte Code Cache** like APC or OPCache?

Comment: You might want to add the cache implementation or cache drivers to the question. I get this error quite often with Redis.

Answer (score 2):

It is permission of the folder.
On Ubuntu in the folder of project:

```
sudo chmod 700 -R var/
```

Comment: you almost never need 777. 777 is like devil's 666 but for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by prefixing `sudo` to the command that I was calling.
Thanks everyone for your help.